# Footer refuses to stick at the bottom

Tags: php, css

I have just recently got into coding, hence the messy code and css (http://codepen.io/valik140795/pen/zBgXRg) . I am currently struggling to position my footer underneath the second grey box with 5 images (instead of being next to it). I have tried countless posts from this website and other sources with no luck. Please help. Thank you in advance.

```
      .block_footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.block_footer` selector is in a media query that targets 100px - 1000px. Remove this selector from the media query if you want it to apply to desktop as well.

Change your numeric `width` and `height` values. You are probably looking for pixels. For example `200px` instead of `200`.

Remove `position: fixed` and use `clear: both`. [Here is more information on `clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

**[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLXbQb)**

Comment: How did you change the selectors precisely? Is there a way to get in touch with you, to perhaps ask a few more small questions like this, if you have time, please?

Comment: @Valbone I just removed the selector from the media query. The media query is the line that says `@media only screen and (min-width:100px) and (max-width:1000px)` - this tells everything inside it to only apply when the browser is a certain width, so I moved the selector from outside that. Look at the bottom of the CSS pane of the example I posted. If you have more questions please post them in StackOverflow as separate questions.

Comment: Thank you yet again for the elaboration. Understood, the sole purpose why I asked was not to spam this beautiful website with stupid questions like mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set bottom property of the .block_footer to 0. Then you need to add the appropriate height padding bottom to the body element.

```
.block_footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
} 

.body {
    padding-bottom: 160px;
}
```